# Jersey serialization/deserialization issue: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, deserialization

I'm using jersey for both serialization and deserialization. I've made REST channel on WebLogic using jersey. I have result object with contains abstract class. Jersey adds to the result metadata with this class'es implementation name:

```
{"order":{"@type":"installationOrder",
```

However, the same jersey, when using to deserialize this data, is screaming the following:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of ocl.mobile.service.data.order.DetailedOrder, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@97eded; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: ocl.mobile.service.OrderDetailsResult["order"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.instantiationException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2376)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1166)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:553)
    ... 5 more
```

but he himself have provided this additional information in the JSON he has serialized.

So, how to make jersey to read and understand this "@type" annotations he have created?

This is how I'm using jersey to read data from channel:

```
private static Client client;

private static void initClient() {
    if (client == null) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    }
}

private static <T> T jsonForResult(String addr, Class<T> expectedClass) {
    initClient();
    WebResource r = client.resource(addr);
    try {
        T result = r.get(expectedClass);
    return result;
        } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The expectedClass is in my case the class of result, which contains status and the abstract class "order", which has implementations such as "installationOrder".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jersey (or more specifically, Jackson JSON lib it uses with POJO mapping) does not add `@type` unless type information inclusion is enabled, usually by adding `@JsonTypeInfo` on an abstract type. So something must have enabled this. Maybe you can share definition `DetailOrder` class?

As to problem itself: this is usually caused by incompatible types used -- type used for deserialization (reading JSON value into POJO) must be such that `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation is visible. You can not, for example, just ask for value of type `java.lang.Object`, since it does not have such annotation. Without knowing actual class definitions it is not possible to point to specific cause, but this is the most likely explanation.

Comment: Im using @XmlSeeAlso to specify all inheriting classes (15 :-), without it serialization caused an error. Maybe weblogic add something, I don't know weblogic, I must just integrate with a project unfortunatelly made for him.

Comment: Ah. Yes, `@XmlSeeAlso` is probably translated to equivalent of `@JsonTypeInfo`. That is fine -- it just also needs to be similarly visible. There is also possibility that JAXB annotation introspector extension (it's a Jackson add-on) could have a bug here. One possibility is to try using Jackson as stand-alone first, to see if things work outside of WebLogic, and depending on how that goes, find appropriate fix.

Comment: I've merged all 15 classes into one DTO, so first problem is away. But the class contains lists of objects, and for these @type tags are not generated, so deserialization also fails.

Comment: You need to similarly annotate properties -- `@JsonTypeInfo` is not transitive (although it does apply to contents of Lists, when applied to a List property).

Answer (score 12):

try  [this](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/blob/master/spring/samples/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/samples/pubsub/dto/BaseCommand.java) it works

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ExchangeFormat.class, name = "ExchangeFormat"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeStatus.class, name = "TypeStatus"),
})
public abstract class MapperJsonXml <T>
```

it's the same with xml

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ExchangeFormat.class,TypeStatus.class})
```

Comment: link provided cannot be accessed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to just exclude `type` field, annotate the superclass `@XmlTransient`, as mentioned here: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html

That will make the serialization work as if the superclass fields were in the child class - thus as if there was no inheritance, in which case the `type` field won't be produced.